# autocomplete not displaying data correctly

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-autocomplete

i have an auto-complete code as follow

```
   $("#city").autocomplete({

    source: function( request, response ) {
        term=request.term;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/autocomplete/city/"+term,
            dataType: "html",
            async:false,
            cache:true,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                response(data);
            }

        });                 
    }
});
```

Alerting data produces correct data . in the form 
delhi
kolkata
and so on. But response(data) displays data as 
d
e
l
h
i
all characters in different lines

can anyone explain the error or thw way of doing it correctly?

Comment: What happens if you do `console.log(data)`?

Comment: @user2525513 do a console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) in place of alert and see what appears in the chrome console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using older version of jquery ( <= 1.7)? if so yes you will get it this way, you need to pass array to the `response`. Newer version of jquery will throw the error as it uses `for..in` to iterate, and i guess older version uses for loop to iterate as if you have passed as array your string gets split into characters hence the behavior.

Try this:

```
success: function( data ) {

    response( [data]);
}
```

But if your data is a string of multiple values separated by commas, you could do this:

```
success: function( data ) {

    response(data.split(','));
}
```

Have a look at this **[Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp)** which states how to use this correctly. And a sample **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wVMv2/)** to demonstrate.